# Finding Min of a subset iteratively - (millions of times)

Tags: r, performance, subset, min

I'm looking for faster and more efficient way to perform an "operation" I am currently doing (albeit slowly).
I have a data table with 5 million observations and  10 features (variables). The variables of interest for this operations are three: Price,date_initial,date_final.

Here is what I need to do:
For each observation I need to look in the table and determine whether that observation has the lowest price of all other observations that have the same
date_initial and same date_final.
So essentially for each row I need to look at the appropriate subset in the date and determine the Min price and check whether the current observation == to that min price.

Here is an example: (The result flag is what I am trying to generate)
enter image description here

```
Price   date_initial    date_final   Result_Flag
45      2018-01-01      2018-01-10   No
40      2018-01-01      2018-01-07   Yes
48      2018-01-01      2018-01-10   No
49      2018-01-01      2018-01-10   No
42      2018-01-01      2018-01-10   Yes
69      2018-01-01      2018-01-07   No
```

As you can see the second observation is a "Yes" as it has the lowest price of all observations with the date_initial == 2018-01-01 and date_final == 2018-01-07.
Again, I am looking for an efficient and fast(er)way to do this. My current method works but is very slow. I am using apply to and an ifelse statement. I am also using data tables. Any help on this would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: I formatted your code block to make it readable (highlighted and clicked the code formatting `{}` button in the editor). It would be nice if you go through and add backticks \` around your inline code to improve its formatting.

Comment: And, for reference, please do show the code you are currently using. It will help us (a) make sure we understand your goal and (b) know what level to explain any suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a quick solution:

```
dt[, res := ifelse(Price == min(Price), 'yes', 'no'),  by = .(date_initial, date_final)]
dt
#    Price date_initial date_final Result_Flag res
# 1:    45   2018-01-01 2018-01-10          No  no
# 2:    40   2018-01-01 2018-01-07         Yes yes
# 3:    48   2018-01-01 2018-01-10          No  no
# 4:    49   2018-01-01 2018-01-10          No  no
# 5:    42   2018-01-01 2018-01-10         Yes yes
# 6:    69   2018-01-01 2018-01-07          No  no
```

Using this data:

```
dt = fread("Price   date_initial    date_final   Result_Flag
45      2018-01-01      2018-01-10   No
40      2018-01-01      2018-01-07   Yes
48      2018-01-01      2018-01-10   No
49      2018-01-01      2018-01-10   No
42      2018-01-01      2018-01-10   Yes
69      2018-01-01      2018-01-07   No"
)
```

Comment: i suspect this will be faster: `DT[, res := "n"][
    DT[, .I[which.min(Price)], by=.(date_initial, date_final)]$V1, res := "y"]`

Answer (score 1):

Using base r you could do:

```
transform(df,Result_Flag = factor(Price==ave(Price,date_initial,date_final,FUN=min),,c('No','Yes')))
  Price date_initial date_final Result_Flag
1    45   2018-01-01 2018-01-10          No
2    40   2018-01-01 2018-01-07         Yes
3    48   2018-01-01 2018-01-10          No
4    49   2018-01-01 2018-01-10          No
5    42   2018-01-01 2018-01-10         Yes
6    69   2018-01-01 2018-01-07          No
```

Instead of the factor, you could use `ifelse`. Also you could do:

```
 library(tidyverse)
 df%>%
    group_by(date_initial,date_final)%>%
    mutate(Result_Flag=factor(Price==min(Price),label=c('No','Yes')))
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   date_initial, date_final [2]
  Price date_initial date_final Result_Flag
  <int> <fct>        <fct>      <fct>      
1    45 2018-01-01   2018-01-10 No         
2    40 2018-01-01   2018-01-07 Yes        
3    48 2018-01-01   2018-01-10 No         
4    49 2018-01-01   2018-01-10 No         
5    42 2018-01-01   2018-01-10 Yes        
6    69 2018-01-01   2018-01-07 No
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is faster than your function, but lets try :)

```
testdata = matrix(c(
45,      "2018-01-01",      "2018-01-10",   
40,      "2018-01-01",      "2018-01-07",   
48,      "2018-01-01",      "2018-01-10",   
49,      "2018-01-01",      "2018-01-10",   
42,      "2018-01-01",      "2018-01-10",   
69,      "2018-01-01",      "2018-01-07"), ncol = 3, byrow = T)   

testdata[,1] = as.numeric(testdata[,1])

testdata = data.table(testdata)
names(testdata) = c("price", "date_i", "date_f")

# create a table with min values for all date_i date_f combinations
lowest = testdata[,list(min = min(price)), list(date_i, date_f)]

# attach the min-values to your dataframe by date_i and date_f
# there might be a faster data.table merge function
testdata = merge(testdata, lowest, by = c("date_i", "date_f"), all.x = T)

# if price is bigger than min write No to result, else yes
testdata$result = ifelse(testdata$price > testdata$min, "No", "Yes")
```